# this keyword in angular js shows Type Error

Tags: angularjs, jqlite

I want to target and element which is clicked in angular but without jQuery.

```
$scope.hide = function() {
    this.querySelector('ul').style.display = 'none'
};
```

But I am getting this error:

> TypeError: this.querySelector is not a function.

I am new to Angular. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Just about a duplicate of ["How does the “this” keyword work?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: `querySelector` is a property on `document`.  if you are doing `document` level HTML changes, you are probably thinking about your application logic incorrectly for angular.  you should try using `ng-show`, `ng-if`, or similar instead.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542#15012542 for more examples of how to think in angular.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` inside that function will not refer to the object you think it refers to (try debugging and/or logging it). I suggest reading up on [how the `this` keyword works in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

Instead, you're looking to do just [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

At any rate, the "Angular way" to show/hide things is using a directive like [`ngShow`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow). E.g.:

```
$scope.isVisible = true;
$scope.hide = function() { $scope.isVisible = false; };
```

```html
<div ng-show="isVisible">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword is a reference to an object. Here you don't have an object so no point of referencing it. That's why it says query selector is not a function cause your `this` isn't defined. Change `this` with `document`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.hide = function() {
    document.querySelector('ul').style.display = 'none'
};
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add a comment as to why this is the answer. It helps learning and understanding for the questioner and the future readers.